# Why are the maps $\eta, \mu, \Delta, \varepsilon$ linear?

Tags: vector-spaces, linear-transformations, hopf-algebras, quantum-groups, coalgebras

Here is the question I am trying to solve:

(Divided powers) Consider the vector space $C = k[t]$ of polynomials in one variable. Prove that there exists a unique coalgebra structure $(C, \Delta, \varepsilon)$ on $C$ such that $$\Delta(t^n) = \sum_{p + q = n} t^p \otimes t^q \text{ and } \varepsilon(t^n) = \delta_{n0}$$ for all $n \geq 0.$ Show that $C$ becomes a bialgebra when given the product $$t^pt^q = t^p t^q = {p+q \choose p} t^{p+q}.$$

**My questions are:**

1-To prove the first part of the question the two maps $\Delta, \epsilon$ should be linear but I do not know the reason they are linear. Could someone clarify this to me please?

2- To prove the second part of the question, the two maps $\eta, \mu $ should be linear but I do not know the reason, could someone clarify this to me please? $\eta$ (defined on the field $k$) and $\mu$(defined on a tensor product of basis elements)

Here are the figures describing the commutativity of the 4 maps:

> [image]

> [image]

> [image]

> [image]

Comment: Any function defined arbitrarily on a basis of a vector space $V$ extends uniquely to a linear function on the whole of $V$.

Comment: Is this a theorem? do you have a reference for it if so? Also what about $\eta$ (defined on the field $k$) and $\mu$(defined on a tensor product of basis) @AndreaMori

Comment: You can call it a theorem if you want but in fact it is a rather trivial standard fact discussed in every linear algebra textbook. If $\{v_i\}_{i\in I}$ is a basis of the vector space $V$ and $\{w_i\}_{i\in I}$ is any set of vectors on the vector space $W$ there's a unique linear map $f:V\rightarrow W$ such that $f(v_i)=w_i$. Just let $f(\sum_ia_iv_i)=\sum_ia_iw_i$. Mind that if $|I|=\infty$ only a finite number of $a_i$ can be $\neq0$.

Comment: When you say $\{w_i\}_{i \in I}$ any set of vectors on the vector space $W,$ that does not mean they are basis for it. right? Also, what about the rest of my question in my previous comment? note that in the statement of the question there is no definition for $\eta$ for example @AndreaMori